# Consume same message by 2 replicas kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a requirement where I want to publish the same kafka message to 2 replicas of kubernetes pods so that I can keep both the replicas in sync.
As our nodes get repaved frequently I don't want us to lose any data.
On the other hand we need our pod to be highly available and scalable.
Any help on above would be appreciated.

Comment: Kafka is a data stream, not a pub/sub like AMQP. Kafka does not publish to consumers, instead, consumers read from the persistent stream while storing an offset. Nothing prevents you from reading the same data from multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve resilience  by just having one of the pods consume each message. To achieve this you setup your kafka library in a way that your consumers are in the same consumer group.

If you really want to consume each message twice or more, you can have 2 or more consumer groups and assign a number of pods to each group. each consumer group will consume the message only once.

For spring this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/) could be helpful, look at the consumer props

Comment: Thanks you @Farhad , As I am new can you please tell me how can i assign pod number to each consumer group. Any example ?

Comment: you should do this in the application code (or using env variables). consumer groups are just text strings like group1 and group2. another idea would be to have 2 deployments with 1 pod each, then each deployment will have its own env variable set to a different consumer group name

Comment: I got it but how to get pod name in java code once pod is in intialization phase.

Comment: the pod name is not a good idea, because each consumer group will start consuming from the beginning of the topic meaning if your pod gets restarted, it will come up with a new name considering its controlled by a deployment. then the pod will start consuming from the beginning instead of continuing where it left off. I would use environment variables

Comment: I am using statefulset so podname will be suffix 0 or 1.